# My 2D maze solver recurses infinitely and I get a stack overflow - why?

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, stack-overflow, maze

**The Problem :-**

I am trying to solve a 2d maze navigation problem in C++ using 2-dimensional array.  To give a concise idea about the problem itself, I intend to navigate from node 'S' in the array to node 'G' by walking through free spaces denoted by '.' The nodes '#' are obstacles. One is not allowed to move on spaces denoted as obstacles. Care must also be taken to make all moves as legal moves (within configuration space). I denote the valid move with a '+' after replacement of the '.' If you like to know more about this problem (not necessary) then please refer this [link](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/alg/maze/).

**What is the issue ?**

I coded a recursive algorithm for this problem where we receive an array and a start node position, and then try to navigate to the goal node using recursion. However, I am getting a stack overflow error. It seems like my recursion never stops. I strongly believe there is some problem in my play() function or my check() function. I am not sure what actually is the problem.

**What did I try ?**

I am reproducing my code below :

```
void spawn(std::string (&board)[6]) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        std::cout << board[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

bool check(size_t a, size_t b, const std::string (&board)[6]) {
    if (a < board[1].size() && a >= 0 && b < board[1].size() && b >= 0) {
        if (board[a][b] == '#' || board[a][b] == '+')
            return false;
        else if (board[a][b] == '.')
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void play(std::string (&board)[6], size_t a, size_t b) {
    auto status = check(a, b, board);
    if (board[a][b] == 'G' || board[a][b] == 'g') {
        spawn(board);
        return;
    }
    if (status) {
        board[a][b] = '+';
        play(board, ++a, b);
        play(board, --a, b);
        play(board, a, ++b);
        play(board, a, --b);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string grid[6] = {{"S#####"},
                           {".....#"},
                           {"#.####"},
                           {"#.####"},
                           {"...#.G"},
                           {"##...#"}};
    play(grid, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One thing is that when you back out from a step, you'll need to reset that '+' back to a '.'

Comment: You probably want to use `a + 1`, `a - 1`, etc. when expanding to a new spot rather than `++a` and `--a`. Imagine a is 1. `++a` makes it 2, then `--a` makes it 1 again when you really wanted 2 and 0. As always, using a debugger to step through the code to make sure what you think is happening is actually what is happening is a good start.

Comment: Don't forget to cite this page when you turn in your assignment, to avoid academic dishonesty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `check` function prevents recursion because it sees the 'S' in the grid at the starting location.  Changing:

```
else if (board[a][b] == '.')
```

to

```
else if (board[a][b] == '.' || board[a][b] == 'S')
```

got it to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the insights Perette and Retired Ninja. I refactored the play() and check() functions in light of your suggestions and also some more ideas by myself.

I figured out that **the main issue** with the segmentation fault error was **not providing accommodation for the '\0' character** at the end of array of strings `grid`. I overlooked it because I considered array of strings to function in a different way than array of chars (since they are not the same species). Now I realize that the '\0' is necessary even for an array of strings !

I am reproducing the refactored functions for the purpose of completeness of this post :

```
void spawn(std::string board[6]) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
       std::cout << board[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

bool check(int a, int b, const std::string board[6]) {
    if (a < board[1].size() && a >= 0 && b < 
        board[1].size() && b >= 0) {
        if (board[a][b] == '#' || board[a][b] == '+') {
            return false;
        } else if (board[a][b] == '.' || 
                   board[a][b] == 'S' || 
                   board[a][b] == 'G') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void play(std::string board[6], int a, int b) {
    if (board[a][b] == 'G' || board[a][b] == 'g') {
        board[0][0] = 'S';
        spawn(board);
        return;
    }
    if (board[a][b] == '.' || board[a][b] == 'S') 
        board[a][b] = '+';
    if (check(a + 1, b, board)) play(board, a + 1, b);
    if (check(a - 1, b, board)) play(board, a - 1, b);
    if (check(a, b + 1, board)) play(board, a, b + 1);
    if (check(a, b - 1, board)) play(board, a, b - 1);
    if (board[a][b] == '+') board[a][b] = '.';
}

int main() {
    std::string grid[7] = {{"S#####"},
                           {".....#"},
                           {"#.####"},
                           {"#.####"},
                           {"...#.G"},
                           {"##...#"}};
    play(grid, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```